# What is the chronological order of Friday the 13th franchise?

Tags: chronology, friday-the-13th, freddy-vs-jason, jason-x

Most of the Friday the 13th films seems to be same chronological order as their release order (excluding 2009's reboot) but I am confused about where *Jason X* and *Freddy vs. Jason* takes place or are they even considered canon? As *Jason X* released before *Freddy vs. Jason* but in the end of *Jason X*, Jason becomes Über Jason and end up on Earth II but *Freddy vs. Jason* seems to be taken place in Earth I only with older Jason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Friday the 13th Wiki](http://fridaythe13th.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_the_Friday_the_13th_series), only Jason X is out of order.

They list the years that each film took place:

- Friday the 13th - 1979
- Friday the 13th Part 2 - 1984
- Friday the 13th Part III - 1984 (A direct continuation of part 2)
- Friday the 13th: The Final Chapter - 1984 (A direct continuation of part III)
- Friday the 13th: A New Beginning - 1989
- Friday the 13th Part VI: Jason Lives - 1990
- Friday the 13th Part VII: The New Blood - 2000
- Jason Goes to Hell: The Final Friday - 2003
- Freddy vs. Jason - 2003
- Jason X - 2455

Jason X was clearly intended to take place in the distant future; so it makes sense that any other Jason movies that were made after it wouldn't be expected to be in chronological order after it.